Make maximum number of requests in parallel
In my .net 8 console application I'm trying to max out concurrent requests using http client.
I know for the fact that server API does not have any throttling.
In Main I'm setting min/max thread pool threads
ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out var max, out var maxIoThreads);
ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out var min, out var minIoThreads);

ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(2000, 500);`

Max connections per server is set to 10k
services.AddHttpClient("3rdPartyApi", client =>
{
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
})
.ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler
{
    MaxConnectionsPerServer = 10_000
})
.AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicy());

Ephemeral port range is more than 10k
netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp

I'm making http calls this way
var requests = items.Select(item => httpClient.GetStringAsync("...")));
await Task.WhenAll(requests);

Note, I deliberately don't want to control level of concurrency. My idea is to queue all http requests, let httpclient handle the rest. As I said there are no concerns of rate limiting. For resiliency there are retry Polly policies, but I don't see any request failing/being retried.
With all this setup, I don't even see 100 concurrent requests
dotnet-counters monitor --process-id 52688 -c System.Net.Http

How do I max out concurrent requests that httpclient makes?

Can you please add code how do you get httpClient? Also can you please share a full [mre]?

I get httpClient like this :
var httpClient = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("3rdPartyApi");
Minimal reproducible example would be challenging as credentials and 3rd party API can't be shared.

Why do you want to bombard a server in the first place?

@PeterCsala I don't want to bombard the server, I want to utilize all resources I have to make requests since underlying API does not have rate limiting.

To downvoter, what's wrong with the question?

Have you tried to run your code to issue requests against a locally running REST API?
